# Не получается центрировать vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify

Все никак не получается отцентрировать по центру.

У меня есть пагинация которая подгружает карточки с новостями, но когда я перехожу на последнюю страницу, центрирование не по центру.
Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно? Уже больше часа просидел, но все без толку

```
<template>
  <v-container class="fill-height">
    <h1 class="titleText mb-6 mt-4">
      Актуальные финансовые новости:
    </h1>
    <v-row>
      <v-expansion-panels class="d-flex justify-start">
        <v-col
          md="2"
          xs="6"
          v-for="(news, index) in newsCurretnPage"
          :key="index"
        >
          <v-expansion-panel class="mb-4">
            <v-img height="250" :src="news.imageurl"></v-img>
            <v-expansion-panel-header>
              <h4>{{ news.title }}</h4>
            </v-expansion-panel-header>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <div class="pb-4">
                {{ news.body }}
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div class="pt-2">
                <p class="mb-0">
                  Источник
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ news.source }}</span>
                </p>
                <a target="_blank" :href="news.url" class="text-decoration-none"
                  >Перейти к источнику</a
                >
              </div>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-col>
      </v-expansion-panels>
    </v-row>
    <div class="pagination">
      <v-pagination
        v-model="pageNumber"
        :length="pages"
        total-visible="8"
        circle
      ></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: justify-start заменить justify-center? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-justify

Comment: @АлексейОбухов я имею ввиду выровнять не 2 карточки по центру, а сам блок, актуальной информации по вертикали. align items не работает (

Comment: Добавь класс `align-stretch` контейнерному элементу, убрав у дочерних элементов все явные указания высоты (разве что у изображения карточки имеет смысл оставить стиль `height`, а остальное должно тянуться под высоту флекс-строки).